# CakePHP: How to send $_GET params like id[]=1&id[]=2&id[]=3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.5

when having the following code:

```
<?= $this->Html->link('Foobar', ['?' => ['id' => [1, 2, 3]]] ?>
```

The output is the following:

```
…id%5B0%5D=1&amp;id%5B1%5D=2&amp;id%5B2%5D=3
```

1. How is it possible to get the (more frequently used) syntax without an array-index like 0, 1, 2.
2. Is there any difference between %5B and [? (yes, i know, it's url escaped)

Comment: in php terms, %5B and [ in the url are identical. everything gets url decoded when PHP is building $_GET, so you should never see %5B when dealing with $_GET. In practical terms, the encoded version is 3x as big, and could lead to a truncated url if you're adding "a lot" of such parameters to the url - browsers do have length limits on urls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like, CakePHP is using php's [http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) method internally. as described in the official docu, this method outputs an array in this format:

```
…id%5B0%5D=1&amp;id%5B1%5D=2&amp;id%5B2%5D=3
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this?

```
<?= $this->Html->link('Foobar', ['?' => ['id' => ['1,2,3']]] ?>
```

I don't see much sense in what you try otherwise. Just explode() the string on the server side and you get your array with a less fugly and long URL.

I *guess* you're trying, or at least it looks like that, to send *form data* via *get*. It is obvious that the default link (it's a link not a form!) method of the HtmlHelper *won't* do that because you would have to specify duplicate array keys.

Try using the [FormHelper::postLink()](http://api.cakephp.org/2.6/class-FormHelper.html#_postLink) method and set the method to `get`. If that doesn't work extend the Form or HtmlHelper and implement what you need by overloading the methods or adding a new method.

Comment: this is not the output i would like to have. this would lead to id[]=1,2,3 and not id[]=1&id[]=2&id[]=3

Comment: Why the downvote!? You could have explained it like that in the first place. See my updated answer.

Comment: hi @burzum! i explained the prefered syntax directly in the question itself. so there shouldn't have been any doubts how the "correct" output should look like. passing array values via get params in the mentioned format is quite common. php's http_build_query method is the same: http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php (which is probably the answer to my question)